# ARM assembly - code to replace character on a string

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I have this C driver program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void subs( char *string, char this_c, char that_cr ) ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char this_c= 'e' ;  
    char that_c = 'X' ;
    char orgstr[] = "sir sid easily teases sea sick seals" ;

    subs( orgstr, this_c, that_c ) ;
    printf( "Changed string: %s\n", orgstr ) ;

    exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

I have to make an arm program that changes the 'e' on the String to 'x', so far this is what I have \

```
.global subs

subs:   
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr} //string entry
    mov v1, #0 //set index to 0
    mov v2, #0 // set count to 0


loop :
    ldrb    v3, [a1,v1] // get the first char
    cmp     a2,v3    //compare char if its the same to the one that has to b chang
    mov v3, a3   // change the character for the new character
    addeq   v2, v2, #1 //increment count
    add     v1, v1, #1 // increment index
    cmp v3,#0   //end of string
    bne     loop
    mov     a1,v2 //return value

    ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
.end
```

This is giving me an infinite loop though and I'm stuck, can anyone help me figure out where the problem is??

---

So this is what i have so far,

```
.global subs

subs:   
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr} //string entry
    mov v1, #0 //set index to 0
    mov v2, #0 // set count to 0


loop :
    ldrb    v3, [a1,v1] // get the first char
    cmp     a2,v3    //compare char if its the same to the one that has to b chang
    moveq   v3, a3   // change the character for the new character
    addeq   v2, v2, #1 //increment count
    add     v1, v1, #1 // increment index
    cmp v3,#0   //end of string
    bne     loop
    mov     a1,v2 //return value

    ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
.end
```

it runs but the character is never changed..., the output and the end is the same one as the input,  for some reason, the a2 registry is null...

Answer (score 1):

This line is completely wrong

```
mov v3, a3   // change the character for the new character
```

This should be a conditional store back into the string.

```
streqb a3, [a1, v1]
```

Comment: i changed the mov to moveq, now it doesnt give me an infinite loop anymore but the string comes out just like the original one, no changes where made

Comment: It needs to be an STR not a mov. MOV won't change the string in memory, just the contents of the register.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the instruction I think you should use. Please post the exact text of the error message if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Error: bad instruction `strbeq a3,[a1,v1]    this is the error im getting now

Comment: if i use the line streq  a3, [a1, v1] it runs but the string that comes out is the original one, no change is made

Comment: @user1773469: Try `streqb` instead of `strbeq`. Some compilers want the condition before the `b`.

Comment: now it runs, however, the output is still the same, no change was made to the string

Comment: this might be a little old, but yeah, i got it to work, i dont remember how though, thx for all the help btw

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Is this for homework?

`mov v3, a3` overwrites `v3` with the new character unconditionally and is never written back to memory (like Pete Fordham noted). Since you also use `v3` when checking for the end of the string, you will never terminate the loop since you just changed `v3` into `a3`. You are also setting a return value for a function which is declared as `void` which will give problems if you ever attempt to use the return value in the C-code.

I would probably do something like this instead (untested but should give you some ideas):

```
loop:
    ldrb v3, [a1], #1
    cmp a2, v3
    strbeq a2, [a1, #-1]
    cmp v3, #0
    bne loop
```

Comment: mmm, that gave me an idea but in that loop you never change the char to the new char...since the X char is stored in a3 and u never use it there, if u do i dont see it, i am new at arm

Comment: @Leo You should do the post increment on the strb to simplify things. If it's ARMv7 you could also use CBNZ instead of CMP + BNE.

Comment: @PeteFordham: Since the strb is conditional I cannot really see how doing the post increment there works. Regarding CBNZ: Thanks for the tip, hadn't noticed that they had added an instruction for that.

Comment: @user1773469: I think you are missing how memory manipulation works. When you do `mov v3, a3` you are setting the register `v3` to `a3`. This will not change anything in the string since the string is stored in memory. If you want to change the string you will have to do some kind of writing to memory, in this case `strbeq`. Since you can write any register to memory, there is no reason to first set `v3` to `a2`.

Comment: i changed that line to  streqb a3, v3      and i am getting this : Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

Comment: @user1773469: Yes, `streqb a3, v3` is not valid assembly code. You should probably read up a bit in the ARM assembly reference on how store operations work and how to write them.

Comment: @PeteFordham: Just noticed that `CBNZ` is thumb only, so that is not really useful here either.