# ARM Assembly function to replace a specific character in a string

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm writing ARM assembly function that replaces a specific character in a string with another and counts the number of times the replacement occurs at the end. So far i have done this:

```
.global subs    
subs:   
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr} //string entry
    mov v1, #0 //set index to 0
    mov v2, #0 // set count to 0       
loop :
    ldrb v3, [a1], #1
    cmp a2, v3
    strbeq a2, [a1, #-1]
    cmp v3, #0
    bne loop
    mov     a1,v2 //return value    
    ldmfd   sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
.end
```

Its not giving the right output. Its showing only first character. Equivalent code in C language is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int replace( char * s, char lr, char rp ) ;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
int result ;
char lr = 'e' ;
char rp = 'X' ;
char str[] = "easy to replace" ;

result = replace( str, lr, rp ) ;
printf( "%d changes, %s\n", result, str ) ;

exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

Comment: OK, so what _is_ the output, and how does it differ from what you expect? What's _your_ understanding of what the code "so far" does? Dumping some code and saying "it doesn't give the right output" does not constitute a question - of _course_ it's not going to give the right output if it's not even finished...

Comment: Thanks for reply, its not making loop and only displaying first character. And i'm beginner for assembly, did not know exact issue, and unable to find it. That's why asking for help from GOOD PEOPLE.

Comment: But there's no code here that displays anything. There's also no information about how this function is called, and with what data; what the role of each register is _supposed_ to be; what particular thing each instruction you've used is _supposed_ to be achieving. It's impossible to debug an out-of-context code fragment without at least some of that information. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your guidelines, i updated my question again. Check it again please.

Comment: `subs` isn't a particularly good name for a function in ARM assembly since that's also the name of the ARM instruction that performs subtraction and updates the status flags. And it obviously doesn't match the name `replace` that you're using in your C code.

Comment: Did you copy this from some MIPS assembly? In ARM the registers are simply called `rN`, except `lr, pc, sp, ip`.

Comment: This is a confused re-post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257266/arm-assembly-code-to-replace-character-on-a-string/36187804#36187804, with worse formatting. The C isn't the equivalent of the asm, it's a program that calls the asm.